# Sequence of Exponential Functions Inequality

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis

Let $f_n(x)=(1-\frac{x}{n})^ne^{x/2}$ when $x\in [0,n]$ and 0 otherwise.
Clearly $f_n\to e^{-x/2}$ pointwise.

What I suspect, and am having trouble proving, is that $f_n(x)\leq e^{-x/2}$. Outside of $[0,n]$ is clear enough, but inside the interval is just messy.

Comment: Isn't this missing an extra exponential piece after factoring? if you factor $e^{-x/2}$ out that leaves a factor of $e^x$ attached to the term which comes from $f_n(x)$.

Comment: You’re right. I read $f_n$ incorrectly

Comment: I don't think your problem is well posed. How can you discuss a pointwise limit if the choice of $x$ is dependent on $n$? For example take $x=n$ then the pointwise limit you have is not correct.

Comment: @Zeta-Squared This came up in the context of measure theory, so even if it wasn’t pointwise convergent on $\mathbb{N}$ it wouldn’t affect the overall result as it’s a set of measure 0

Answer (score 1):

I think I solved it actually.

Consider the difference
$$f-f_n(x)=e^{-x/2}\left(1-\left(1-\frac{x}{n}\right)e^x\right).$$
Since $e^{-x/2}>0$ for all $x$ it suffices to show that $1-(1-\frac{x}{n})e^x\geq 0$ on $[0,n]$, or that $1\geq (1-\frac{x}{n})e^x$. Let $g_n(x)=(1-\frac{x}{n})e^x$. This function is continuous on a compact set, so it achieves its bounds, which must occur at either the endpoints or the critical points. Note that
$$g_n'(x)=e^x\left[\left(1-\frac{x}{n}\right)^n-\left(1-\frac{x}{n}\right)^{n-1}\right]$$
which is 0 only when $x=0$ or $x=n$. Therefore, $g_n(x)$ achieves minimum of $0$ when $x=n$, and a maximum of $1$ when $x=0$, which is what we needed to show.